# Haml for rails, Use 'haml' gem alone or with 'haml-rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, erb

I am making the switch to Haml for our rails 3.1 application, and I wonder what is bringing to the table by the `'haml-rails'` gem against `'haml'` alone, apart rails generators?

It says that it preloads the haml in rails process. Does it means a lot of benefits in performance? We are mixing erb and haml so it doesn't seems to be so good to preload every time the haml library.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use haml-rails primarily to make the generators output haml views instead of erb.  Beyond that, I'm not aware of any difference.

Comment: I think it's just the generators, although now that you say it out loud, I'm not as sure ;)

Comment: "Haml-rails provides Haml generators for Rails 3. It also enables Haml as the templating engine for you, so you don't have to screw around in your own application.rb when your Gemfile already clearly indicated what templating engine you have installed. Hurrah."